# Input file upload is not working inside Angular Material Menu

Tags: angular, file-upload, menu, angular-material

I have Angular Material Menu & placed input file upload control. The file choosing window is not coming when I click on the file upload control. It is not working because the file input is there inside the Angular material menu.

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
<input type="file"/> 
</mat-menu>
```

If any suggestions to work the input file type inside the menu

Comment: I think your problem come from another part of your code, could you provide a Stackblitz example reproducing it.
A minimal working example: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erwgqj](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erwgqj)

Comment: It is inside a form. I put the input upload outside. It is working.Thanks. Now another problem the menu is closing when clicking on browser button. Is there any way to not close the menu when I click on the browse button.

Comment: `<input (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" type="file"/> ` should do the job.

Comment: All issues are fixed...thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is working outside a form:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
  <input (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" type="file"/> 
</mat-menu>
```

`(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` allows you to keep the menu open after clicking on the "Browse" button of the input.